# Is there any way to "wait here..." in code - just like an empty loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, semaphore, promise, nsnotificationcenter

Consider this code:

```
[self otherStuff];
// "wait here..." until something finishes
while(!self.someFlag){}
[self moreStuff];
```

Note that this all happens **ON THE SAME THREAD** - we do not want to go to another thread.

otherStuff could do things like connect to the cloud, get input from the user, etc. so it would take a lot of time and could follow many possible paths.

otherStuff would set self.someFlag to true, when otherStuff is finally finished.

This works perfectly and there's no problem with it at all -- except that it's lame to burn up the processor like that with the empty loop!!

Quite simply, is there a way to say something like ..

```
halt here, until (some message, interrupt, flag, boolean, whatever?)
```

Rather than just while(!self.someFlag){}

(Note the alternative is to "chain" the procedures ... so at the end of "otherStuff", you and all the other programmers have to "just know" that you have to next call "moreStuff", regardless of how otherStuff plays out, etc. Of course, that is very messy when you have to add new procedures or change the order of things.)  Cheers!!

BTW there are already two excellent answers below regarding the situation when you want **DIFFERENT THREADS**.

Comment: I think you should think about NSLock and NSCondition. It is more proper way instead of infinite cycles.

Comment: I'm just curious. Why do you need such an inline solution?

Comment: malex -- Hmm, I don't really see how NSLocking would help here. Maybe I'm missing something.  Andrey - look at the first example imaginary code block. It would be incredibly easy / elegant to move items around, add items, and so on.  Go ahead and write out a non-inline solution!

Comment: What are you waiting on?

Comment: will `sleep(1000000)` meet your question ? Can `waithere` resume, if it can, when to resume?

Comment: Hi Kudo, "sleep" is totally unrelated, cheers.

Comment: Josh - that's an excellent point, implicit in my question is that the other processes go and do something (it could be the "user enters address details" or "File Download" or "play one round of the minigame", or whatever). So quite simply in the first example, the first waitHere would wait for me to send some sort of notification (semaphore?, interrupt?, whatever) in "someOtherStuff".  Again - to repeat - you can do this utterly perfectly using "a boolean" and an empty loop (while(!self.flag){}) - but of course that's lame. It's a straightforward question - how to halt until a signal!

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution using a semaphore, be careful not to introduce a deadlock - you need some way of telling your application something has finished, you can either do that using the `NSNotificationCentre` like you suggested but using a block is *much* easier.

```
[self someOtherStuffWithCompletion:nil];

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[self someOtherStuffWithCompletion:^{
  dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];

NSLog(@"waiting");
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
NSLog(@"finished");

[self someOtherStuffWithCompletion:nil];
```

Comment: Oliver, thank you so much ... ahhh.  Well now ... this entirely happens on the "same" thread, is that correct?  (ie: you don't have to send someOtherStuffWithCompletion to another thread, or anything like that?)  thanks!

Comment: TBC, when you say avoid a deadlock, do you mean: "don't forget to" eventually call dispatch_semaphore_signal?  Or something more hideous I don't understand?  :)  Thanks!

Comment: `someOtherStuffWithCompletion` needs to happen on another thread you are correct

Comment: Ah, another thread, I see -- crap!  I'm looking for a solution just on the same thread.  Damn I have to make the question clearer, sorry!  Still incredibly useful though ........  thanks again

Comment: If you are doing the work on the same thread then you dont need to wait, the next operation will only execute once the previous one has finished - thats the way computers work.

Comment: heh for sure! got you.   :)  but what I mean is either: (A) otherStuff might be "let the user input their address in five fields": otherStuff would only let everyone know it is finished when that is completely done, or, (B) picture otherStuff doing numerous calculations and indeed ("on its own") going to the cloud a few times for this and that (TBC, otherStuff - completely "on its own" - may or may not wait for the cloud a few times, and that could lead to error conditions, alternate paths or whatever else); only when all that is completely finished otherStuff would indicate "all done".

Comment: if its all happening on the same thread you don't need a completion state, its only when you deal with multiple threads that you need to make one wait. your best bet would be to make an example project to show your problem if you still don't understand the solution from the current ones provided.

Comment: thanks again.  just TBC, can I send dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) on **this** thread?  so my method otherStuff does things, waits for a download, does more things, waits for a download, and there (I propose) on **this** thread it calls dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore).  Is that OK?  thanks!!

Comment: If you are downloading you want it to happen on the background thread so you don't lock up the UI. If you want it to lock the UI you don't need a semaphore your example would work fine - but its not the right solution. Read this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#mainthread

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a NSOperationQueue and to wait for all tasks until they are finished at specific points. Something like that:

```
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

// Ensure a single thread
self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

// Add the first bunch of methods
[self.queue addOperation:[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(method1) object:nil]];
[self.queue addOperation:[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(method2) object:nil]];
[self.queue addOperation:[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(method3) object:nil]];

// Wait here
[self.queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

// Add next methods
[self.queue addOperation:[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(method4) object:nil]];
[self.queue addOperation:[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(method5) object:nil]];

// Wait here
[self.queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
```

HTH

Comment: Great thinking -- but those guys would all be on different threads right?

Comment: Not if you set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1.

Comment: Marcio is totally right. I updated the code example above to reflect this behaviour.

Comment: Hmm guys, I'm wondering, if you set .maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1, does that put all of them **on (1) NEW (different) thread**?  or does it keep all of them on "our" same thread? Cheers....

Comment: In one **new different thread**. But I think you want to have it all in the same thread. Or maybe on the main thread?

Comment: ahh .. thanks ... yeah, I want it all on the "same thread" as I start off on.  I want it specifically to not use a new thread for anything. this is still an amazingly helpful answer though!  :O